# How is the memory allocation done for ElasticSearch types in an index?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I was reading the `elasticsearch` documentation and found an interesting line written, in [Index vs. Type](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type) under the heading "What is type" the second point says:

> Fields that exist in one type will also consume resources for documents of types where this field does not exist.

I am not able to understand what it actually means. Does it mean ti say if I create two types:

```
Type 1: [a:string, b:text, c:keyword] Type 2: [c: keyword, d:string]
```

Then even if I am storing a document of type 2, the ElasticSearch will take space for all 5 fields? I don't think it should be the case, but looks to be the same, the way it is written in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch is built on top of Lucene, which does not have the concept of a "type". With Lucene, you just have an index and you fill it with documents. A type is an abstraction that only exists at the Elasticsearch layer.

So when you write a document for type 1 then it is like writing this document in Lucene:

{
  "a": "Foo",
  "b": "Bar",
  "c": "Foobar",
  "d": null
}

or for writing to type 2 then:

{
  "a": null,
  "b": null,
  "c": "Foobar",
  "d": "Foobazz"
}

Despite the fact that when you are writing a document for one type, you are leaving the fields blank for the other type, these empty fields can still consume resources in Lucene. For example, both norms and doc_values are still computed on empty fields (assuming they are enabled, which they are by default depending on the field type).

Also worth reading: https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring